# Adding/removing RadioButton/EditText in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to let a user create a survey in my app but I'm struggling with one piece of my code. A user can click "Add answer" and it'll add a RadioButton / EditText. Then on clicking "Remove answer" it should remove those. It works for removing the first Radiobutton / RditText that was added, however if I've already added 2 or more RadioButtons, it throws an error.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

```
mAddAnswer = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addAnswer);
mAddAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RadioButton question = new RadioButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        question.setId(newQuestionRadioId);
        newQuestionRadioId += 1;
        mAnswersGroup.addView(question);

        EditText answer = new EditText(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        answer.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        answer.setId(newQuestionId);
        newQuestionId += 1;
        answer.setHint("Enter answer");
        mAnswerHolder.addView(answer);
        questionNumber += 1;
        }
    });

mRemoveAnswer = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.removeAnswer);
mRemoveAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mAnswersGroup.getChildCount() > 1) {
            mAnswersGroup.removeViewAt(newQuestionRadioId - 1);
            mAnswerHolder.removeViews(questionNumber - 1, questionNumber - 1);
            newQuestionId -= 1;
            newQuestionRadioId -= 1;
            questionNumber -= 1;
        }           
    }
});
```

Logcat:

```
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532): java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewsInternal(ViewGroup.java:2231)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViews(ViewGroup.java:2179)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at com.example.surveymetest.AddQuestionFragment$2.onClick(AddQuestionFragment.java:106)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 02-16 16:39:49.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what error you are receiving?

Comment: A copy of the logcat would be good.

Comment: Can you post the code where `mAnswersGroup` is created? I suspect for some reason it is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the null ponter may happen because of removeViews

The method removeViews is defined in developer site like

```
removeViews(int start, int count)
```

Where the parameters are

```
start  the first position in the group of the range of views to remove 
count  the number of views to remove
```

Count should be the no of views, you want to remove from the view group.